# Why don't working jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, display

Here it's working: [https://jsfiddle.net/w711Lf6t/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/w711Lf6t/1/)

On page don't working.
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="register" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input_class" placeholder="test"/>
        <div id="error_name">Input name!</div>
</form>
</html>
```

js.js

```
function validation() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    if (name === '') {
        $("#error_name").css('display', 'block');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#error_name").css('display', 'none');
    }
}

$("#name").focusout(function () {
    validation();
});
```

css.css

```
#error_name {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

What I forget to add? I try jquery .js, but same problem.

Comment: The browser console is telling you exactly what's wrong.  Look at the error message(s).  For one thing, you didn't include the jQuery library.

Comment: Is `js.js` your jQuery library? If not, you'll need to include it.

Comment: I try to add: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` but same

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `Jquery` before your js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="register" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input_class" placeholder="test"/>
        <div id="error_name">Input name!</div>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: I try to add: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` but same

Comment: @Deimantas see what is your browser console showing!  for example in google chrome :  right click on page ---> inspect elements -----> console tab . what is the error ? show me

Comment: Console is empty.

Comment: @Deimantas you sure?  try to debug something in console to see if it works. like :  `$("#name").focusout(function () {
   console.log("focus out working!!")
});`

Comment: Then in console: `r.fn.init__proto__: Object[0]`

Comment: @Deimantas obviously your code is not running. try  `console.log("working")`  in various lines of your code to see if its working

Comment: I try in 5 lines, get working only in one line after all code.